# Reliable alternative to `time.sleep` [As job does not scrape data without it]

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a job that tends to work with time.sleep.  However, I’m wanting a quicker method than time.sleep(2) as this is slow and would not work where there is slow internet or on my laptop which is slow.

[Full code here.](https://pastebin.com/VfWNTnhz)

The job works for:

```
indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
shuffle(indexes)
for index in indexes:
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/')
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    clickMe.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Changing time.sleep to 0 means the job just finishes successfully [no scraping or actions performed].

Unfortunately,

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.css_selector, "#TopPromotionBetNow"))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
```

Is giving me an error.

```
clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()
```

Does not seem to have an effect,

Any ideas on how I can make it so the job will scrape, navigate, click successfully so that the page is fully loaded?

Comment: use WebDeiverWait.

Comment: What's your expected output from that page? Once we know the to-be output, it would be better to compare if there is really any variation noticed even if `Explicit Wait` is there.

Comment: @SIM Hope this makes sense.  With time.sleep I get about 120 scrapes.  IF you remove that line you will get significantly less (Depends on internet connection and luck).  The desired output is to have it scrape the exact amount as adding time.sleep would give or close to it.  As far as I can tell the reason it happens is because it does not load the elements on page with explicit waiting for some weird reason

Answer (score 0):

You can use [visibility_of_all_elements_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located) as the expected condition

```
langs2 = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@class, "tb_header-bar tb_")]')))
```

Comment: I added that, but it still has same issue.  Surely there must be a viable alternative to time.sleep

Comment: @Tetora Do you know the exact number of elements to expect?

Comment: I've provided an updated script and more detail in the question, it seems that it clicks the elements but the page is not fully loaded meaning it gets duplicate scrapes.  I also tried to incorporate a lot of different wait until's with no luck hence long script

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to scrape/parse the page. The website has an API to request the data directly. You can inspect these requests with devtools (F12) when the page is loading.

To list all the markets with the England Premier League:

```
import requests

URI_COMPETITIONS = "https://services.topbetta.com.au/api/v2/combined/sports/competitions?sport_name=football"
URI_EVENTS = "https://services.topbetta.com.au/api/v2/combined/events/markets/selections?competition_id=%s"

response = requests.get(URI_COMPETITIONS).json()

for sport in response['data'] :
  if sport['name'] == 'Football':

    for base_competition in sport['base_competitions'] :
      if base_competition['name'] == 'England Premier League':

        for info_competition in base_competition['competitions'] :
          response = requests.get(URI_EVENTS % info_competition['id']).json()

          for competition in response['data'] :
            print('%s' % competition['name'])

            for event in competition['events'] :
              print("  %s  %s" % (event['start_date'], event['name']))

              for market in event['markets']:                
                for selection in market['selections'] :
                  print("  %s  %s" % (selection['name'], selection['price']))
```

Which gives:

```
England Premier League Round 26
  2018-02-06 07:00:00  Watford v Chelsea
    Watford  6
    Draw  3.8
    Chelsea  1.6
England Premier League Round 27
  2018-02-11 02:00:00  Everton v Crystal Palace
    Everton  2.4
    Draw  3.2
    Crystal Palace  3
  2018-02-11 23:00:00  Huddersfield Town v AFC Bournemouth
    Huddersfield Town  3
    Draw  3.2
    AFC Bournemouth  2.4
  2018-02-11 04:30:00  Manchester City v Leicester City
    Manchester City  1.2
    Draw  6.5
    Leicester City  13
...
```

Comment: Is there no way to get around this with selenium at all?  I had a look at the network page in chrome inspect, where is there api?  Thanks

Comment: requesting the API directly is the easy way compared to Selenium and it's a lot faster. To view the requests, press F12, got to the network tab, press F5 to reload the page, search for `competition`, select the row and click on preview on the right. You'll see the data used by the page.

Comment: Sounds interesting, though how would I scrape all there pages instead of just this one using their api?

Comment: simply remove both `If ... == ... :` from the code to print the data for all the sports and competitions.

Comment: Is it possible to get the output similar to what I have in my question or is this a limitation of api?
 https://services.topbetta.com.au/api/v2/combined/sports/competition/events?competition_id=154675

Comment: all the data from your post are available in the data from the api. the response is composed of dictionaries and arrays, so select the information you need and structure them according to your needs.